# What should I do to get this code running (without changing the code)

Tags: python-3.x, prime-factoring

I was solving the 3rd Question on Project Euler (Largest Prime Factor) and I'm a beginner at Python 3.

This is the solution I came up with, it works but not with very large numbers

```
x=int(input("Enter a number:"))
a=[]
for i in range(1,x+1):
    cnt=0
    if x%i==0:
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            if i%j==0:
                cnt=cnt+1
        if cnt==2:
            a.append(i)
print(a[len(a)-1])
```

I understand its very basic, and its too slow to run large inputs, but is there any way a compiler could give me the output for this input - 600851475143. I tried using pypy3, it was taking too long as well.

Its my first time I'm using stackoverflow, so let me know if I'm doing anything wrong too.

Comment: If the code has a flaw, you can't really expect to remove it without changing the code. You can't magically make slow code run faster; you really need to come up wrth a less resource-intensive algorithm.

Comment: Why on earth would you add "without changing the code" as a requirement for your question? It's your code, and you *need* to change it if it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Imagine you have a pushbike and you ask, is there anything I can do to the road so that I can I ride at 70mph without changing the bike? The answer is that you don't just need to change the bike, you need a different kind of vehicle.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i apologize for adding that. I understand that I must learn new algorithms/approaches so that my code is more effective and faster. Im assuming you've come across such questions before, so could you please suggest what topic I should start learning/practicing so that I could start solving similar questions with a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want to change the code but you would have to, if you want to solve it efficiently.
There actually a lib just for this `eulerlib` but the built-in `math` module can do it too.

If you want to use python with no modules you could try this but it is probably just as slow for large numbers

```py
def Largest_Prime_Factor(n):
    prime_factor = 1
    i = 2

    while i <= n / i:
        if n % i == 0:
            prime_factor = i
            n /= i
        else:
            i += 1

    prime_factor = max(prime_factor, n)
    return prime_factor
```

The built-in `math` module can also do this and is far quicker. Since it is built-in you don't need any external libs like `eulerlib`

```py
import math

# Getting input from user
n = int(input("Enter the number : "))

maxPrimeFactor = 0
# Checking and converting the number to odd
while n % 2 == 0:
    maxPrimeFactor = 2
    n = n/2

# Finding and dividing the number by all
# prime factors and replacing maxPrimeFactor
for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
    while n % i == 0:
        maxPrimeFactor = i
        n = n / i
if n > 2:
    maxPrimeFactor = n

print("The largest prime Factor of the number is ",int(maxPrimeFactor))
```